# Abortable Fetch in firebase cloud function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm using [abortable fetch](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/abortable-fetch) to timeout fetch queries that are taking too long.

Can `AbortController` be called within Firebase functions?

Cloud Function:

```
exports.afterLike = functions.firestore
.document('users/{userId}/posts/{postId}')
.onUpdate(async (change, context) => {

    ...

    const abortCtrl = new AbortController();
    const signal = abortCtrl.signal;
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        abortCtrl.abort()
    }, 8000)

    fetch('https://posturl.com/api', {
        signal: signal,
        likeId: "123456"
    })
})
```

But AbortController is undefined. here is the firebase function error:

```
ReferenceError: AbortController is not defined
    at res.forEach (/srv/index.js:76:28)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, [AbortController](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController) is a browser web API, and since Cloud Functions doesn't run in a web browser context (it's nodejs, there is no browser head or DOM), so there is no AbortController available.

Comment: Could you suggest a better way to abort the fetch query in a cloud function? (To prevent long queries)

Comment: Promise.race().  But you shouldn't need that because Cloud Functions have a timeout that you can configure as needed.

Comment: Thanks, i didn't realize you could set the timeout in the function. I'm using `.runWith(timeoutSeconds: 20,)`